Has anyone tried “building” any convex uniform polyhedra from combinatorial tree graphs?
CONTEXT
Convex uniform polyhedra, like tree graphs, can be described with vertices and unitary edges.
QUESTION 1
Has anyone tried “building” any convex uniform polyhedra from combinatorial tree graphs ?
PROPOSITION 1
Out of interest in the alternate sum of Motzkin numbers and in the conjectured description of the sum, as stated on oeis.org, with a topologically series-reduced ordered rooted tree, I created a “tree” of this tree configurations/states, ordering them by degrees of the vertex configuration of the 2 main vertices.
An arbitrary imaginary direction is set in this “tree” of the tree to maintain the sign alternation of the conjectured described sum.
Interestingly, considering only the configurations where one of both main vertices is degree 1, one could describe a double canopy in this “tree” of the tree. And interestingly, for the 3 chosen ranks, this canopy follows the same proportion scale (with 6, 12 and 30 configurations) as 3 classes of convex uniform polyhedra (with 12, 24 and 60 vertices), which I described in this question asked.
These are screencaptures of an animation I created to illustrate this.


QUESTION 2
Can this proportion scale similarity be explained ?
PROPOSITION 2
A similar approach to the 5-star tree graph connected subtrees, considering only the “binded” configurations (from yellow to green on the following picture), reveals a total number of edges which is exactly half of the number of edges of a snub dodecahedron. And this polyhedron also belongs to one of the described class.

So 5-star configurations can be spanned over the vertices/surface of a snub dodecahedron. I illustrate this in this short animation. This can be done with the 3-star and the 4-star graphs too, with an irregularity for the 4-star.

QUESTION 2
What method would you recommend to enumerate all possible arrangements of the 5-star tree graph configurations/states over a snub dodecahedron ?
